# Bootstrap tooltip shown instant at second mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html-element which has a title 
`title ="This is a tooltip"` and my class  `class="tooltips"`.

In my script.js is the following code (just for demonstration of my problem):

```js
var timeout;
$('.tooltips').mouseenter(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  if(timeout){
     clearTimeout(timeout); 
   }
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    that.tooltip('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.tooltip('hide');
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" title="I am a tooltip" class="tooltips">Hover me</a>
```

What it should do:
If I enter the element with my pointer, it should happen nothing. After a delay of a second, the tooltip should appear and after another second, the tooltip should disappear.

What actually happens:
The first time it worked how expected, but if I hover the element the second time, the tooltip appears instantly and disappears after two seconds delay. It seems that the first `tooltip('show')` enables the tooltip for appearing on mouseover.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution for this problem.
It seems like that

```
.tooltip('show')
```

is enabling tooltips for this element, so any follwing hovering will display the tooltip.

```js
var timeout;
$('.tooltips').mouseenter(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  if(timeout){
     clearTimeout(timeout); 
   }
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    that.tooltip('enable');
    that.tooltip('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.tooltip('disable');
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" title="I am a tooltip" class="tooltips">Hover me</a>
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear timeout using [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) before re-initializing it like,

```
var that = $(this);
if(timeout){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
```

After the question is updated, you just need to use `destroy` instead of `hide` the `tooltip` and no need to use `clearTimeout`. It is because once the tooltip is created then on next time when your mouseenter on link it will show and hide without any delay and the `setTimeout` is not useful.

```js
var timeout;
$('.tooltips').mouseenter(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    that.tooltip('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.tooltip('destroy');
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" title="I am a tooltip" class="tooltips">Hover me</a>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo for it?